# Compiling static library for Google Native Client using SCons

Tags: scons, google-nativeclient

I'm working on a few multi platform projects that all depend on common framework. 
I want to add support for Google Native-Client (NaCl). The way I aproached the problem is first to compile the framework as static library (this is how I've been doing it on all other platforms).

I have to say that I have never used SCons before. I think I start grasping it. Starting from a build.scons from a tutorial I can get some code compiling and linking. Now I would want to skip the linking process but seems like the nacl_env was never intended to compile static libraries.

Reading the SCons help didn't help me much since the Library node is missing from the nacl_env.

I don't think I understand SCons enough to write the whole build process from scratch so I was hopping to not have to do so.

**1. Am I approaching the problem correctly?**

**2. Any tips or sample nacl static libs, build using SCons?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, what I did is way more trickery than what you probably need.

I wanted my static library to handle the initialization steps of the NaCl module, and then call some project-specific function.

I ended up turning my whole framework and the contents of the built-in libppapi_cpp.a into a single .o file, and then that into a single .a file, a static library.

I needed a single .o file, because otherwise I would run into dependency problems releated to initialization, I could not solve.

**build_lib.sh** (framework):

```
#!/bin/bash -e

SDK="/home/kalmi/ik/nacl_sdk/pepper_15"

function create_allIn_a {
TMPDIR="`mktemp -d`"
  echo $TMPDIR
  cp $O_FILES $TMPDIR
  pushd $TMPDIR &> /dev/null
  $AR x $LIBPPAPI_CPP_A
  $LD -Ur * -o ALL.o
  $AR rvs $OUTPUT_NAME ALL.o
  $RANLIB $OUTPUT_NAME
  popd &> /dev/null
}

./scons


BIN_BASE="$SDK/toolchain/linux_x86/bin"
LD="$BIN_BASE/i686-nacl-ld"
AR="$BIN_BASE/i686-nacl-ar"
RANLIB="$BIN_BASE/i686-nacl-ranlib"
LIBPPAPI_CPP_A="$SDK/toolchain/linux_x86_newlib/x86_64-nacl/lib32/libppapi_cpp.a"
O_FILES="`find $(pwd)/opt_x86_32 | grep .o$ | grep --invert-match my_main.o | tr "\n" " "`"
LIBDIR="../../../bin/lib/lib32"
mkdir -p $LIBDIR
if [ -f $LIBDIR/libweb2grid_framework.a ]; then
  rm $LIBDIR/libweb2grid_framework.a
fi
OUTPUT_NAME="`readlink -m $LIBDIR/libweb2grid_framework.a`"
create_allIn_a


BIN_BASE="$SDK/toolchain/linux_x86/bin"
LD="$BIN_BASE/x86_64-nacl-ld"
AR="$BIN_BASE/x86_64-nacl-ar"
RANLIB="$BIN_BASE/x86_64-nacl-ranlib"
LIBPPAPI_CPP_A="$SDK/toolchain/linux_x86_newlib/x86_64-nacl/lib64/libppapi_cpp.a"
O_FILES="`find $(pwd)/opt_x86_64 | grep .o$ | grep --invert-match my_main.o | tr "\n" " "`"
LIBDIR="../../../bin/lib/lib64"
mkdir -p $LIBDIR
if [ -f $LIBDIR/libweb2grid_framework.a ]; then
  rm $LIBDIR/libweb2grid_framework.a
fi
OUTPUT_NAME="`readlink -m $LIBDIR/libweb2grid_framework.a`"
create_allIn_a

 ./scons -c
```

The my_main.o file is excluded from the static library, because that file contains the function that is to be provided by the project that uses this framework.

The **build.scons** file for the framework is truly ordinary.

**build.scons** (for some project that uses this framework):

```
#! -*- python -*-

#What to compile:
sources = [ 'src/something.cpp', 'src/something_helper.cpp' ]


###############################################################x

import make_nacl_env
import nacl_utils
import os

nacl_env = make_nacl_env.NaClEnvironment(
    use_c_plus_plus_libs=False,
    nacl_platform=os.getenv('NACL_TARGET_PLATFORM'))

nacl_env.Append(
    # Add a CPPPATH that enables the full-path #include directives, such as
    # #include "examples/sine_synth/sine_synth.h"
    CPPPATH=[os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())))],
    LIBS=['web2grid_framework','srpc'],
    LIBPATH=['../../../bin/lib/lib32','../../../bin/lib/lib64'],
    LINKFLAGS=['-pthread']
   )

nacl_env.AllNaClModules(sources, 'client')
```

Some lines worth highlighting:

- use_c_plus_plus_libs=False,
- LIBS=['web2grid_framework','srpc'],
- LIBPATH=['../../../bin/lib/lib32','../../../bin/lib/lib64'],
- LINKFLAGS=['-pthread']

I am not saying that this is a clean method, but it gets the job done.

Comment: The example is useful. That's what I was looking for. Some working example of how to compile static lib for NaCl that I can modify for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

So, there's two questions here
1. Using SCONS:
NaCl uses SCONS for it's examples, simply to help compiling of the examples easier. In reality, SCONS simply directs to the GCC/G++ compilers in the SDK build directories. (SCONS will take the input scripts, and create the final param string to send to GCC)

GCC is a common compiler, and is well documented on the net : http://gcc.gnu.org/

How you integrate NaCl compilation into your work-flow is up to you (ie you're not forced to use SCONS).

For instance, if you'd like to go to GCC directly, you can simply call :
`<path to bin>/x86_64-nacl-gcc -m64 -o test.nexe main.c`

For a more detailed look into how to compile NaCl modules, please read the [documentation @ gonacl.com on compiling](https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/compiling) which will detail how to compile with and without SCONS.

2.Compilng Static libs with GCC
Here is an example : http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html

~Main

Comment: Hmm. For some reason I thought there may be some other stranger steps involved into compiling for NaCl or that maybe there is a step completely implemented in Python. I'll spend some more time trying to fix the scons build but it's good to know I can easily switch to makefile.